# Why does include_graphics not render include_graphics(pdf) images when knitting to bookdown::word_document2

Tags: r, ms-word, bookdown

When knitting to word_document2, when using knitr::include_graphics on a pdf shows "The picture can't be displayed." where the image should be. It does work for .png.

````
```{r pressure, fig.cap = "testing", echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

[image: inline image working]

````
```{r, include = FALSE}
png("pressure.png")
plot(pressure)
dev.off()
```

```{r, include = FALSE}
pdf("pressure.pdf")
plot(pressure)
dev.off()
```

```{r pressure-png, fig.cap = "testing png", echo = FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics("pressure.png")
```
````

[image: png working]

````
```{r pressure-pdf, fig.cap = "testing pdf", echo = FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics("pressure.pdf")
```
````

[image: pdf not working]

Comment: I don't think Word supports PDF images, but I don't use Word, so I could be wrong.

Comment: «I could be wrong» Indeed you are. You can prove that by going to Insert|Object>Object>Create from File, then selecting a PDF to insert. The first page of the PDF will be displayed. The issue for the OP is that he's trying to insert it the wrong way (it's not a picture, as such).

Comment: @YihuiXie is it the same for html files?

Comment: @macropod Thanks! Then it's up to Pandoc if it supports inserting PDF images that way.

Comment: @evanmuise It depends on your web browser. Some browsers support PDF images, but I suspect most browsers don't.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72108773/knitrinclude-graphics-runs-but-image-cannot-be-displayed?noredirect=1#comment127443747_72108773