# knitr::include_graphics runs, but image cannot be displayed

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, bookdown

I wanted to try using `knitr::include graphics` ([link](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html)) in my R-markdown document. I am using it as suggested by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166624/insert-picture-table-in-r-markdown) (using the full path):

````
---
title: "Sample Document"
output:
  word_document
---

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="A caption", out.width = '100%'}
knitr::include_graphics("Z:/../SEM/semflow.png")
```
````

This is the [picture](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/semflow-1024x539.png). I tried installing the `png` package and also tried simply using:

````
```{r}
knitr::include_graphics("Z:/../SEM/semflow.png")
```
````

The code is accepted by `knitr`, which means that it found the file, but it shows up in the Word document like this:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how this could happen?

## Related question

A related question (without an answer) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67427307/why-does-include-graphics-not-render-include-graphicspdf-images-when-knitting).

## Help file: ?knitr::include_graphics

[image]

Comment: Whenever possible, you should use relative paths instead of absolute paths (see the help page `?knitr::include_graphics`). Anyway, without a reproducible example, it's hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: I once had a similar problem where knitr found the file, but the image wasn't found in the resulting document. I was able to solve it by using normalizePath. You might try that. It looks like this: `knitr::include_graphics(normalizePath("../images/whitelogo-blackletter.png"))`

Comment: @jtbayly Thanks, just tried it. Made no difference regrettably.

Comment: @YihuiXie Where does it say that exactly? It is nowhere in my help page..

Comment: Maybe try to get the file path beforehand, e.g. `list.files("SEM/", pattern = ".png", full.names = TRUE)` and pass it then to the `include_graphics()` function.

Comment: @Julian Thank you for your comment. Could you explain why that would maybe make a difference? I did try it, but it did not work.

Comment: Similar to @jtbayly I assumed that the problem lies within the path of the file and that would have been my approach to debug.

Comment: Apparently it was a template issue. When I removed the template I was using it worked perfectly. What do you guys think, should I remove the question or answer it (so that the next person encountering this problem has another idea what to try)?

Comment: @Tom “Where does it say that exactly?” I think you are using an old version of knitr (BTW, it'll be great if you provide the session info every time, e.g., `xfun::session_info('rmarkdown')`). You may [update packages](https://yihui.org/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/) and retry.